# Converting an RPy2 ListVector to a Python dictionary

Tags: python, rpy2

The natural Python equivalent to a named list in R is a dict, but [RPy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) gives you a [ListVector](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html?highlight=listvector#rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector) object.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

a = robjects.r('list(foo="barbat", fizz=123)')
```

At this point, a is a [ListVector](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html?highlight=listvector#rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector) object.

```
<ListVector - Python:0x108f92a28 / R:0x7febcba86ff0>
[StrVector, FloatVector]
  foo: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>
  <StrVector - Python:0x108f92638 / R:0x7febce0ae0d8>
[str]
  fizz: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>
  <FloatVector - Python:0x10ac38fc8 / R:0x7febce0ae108>
[123.000000]
```

What I'd like to have is something I can treat like a normal Python dictionary. My temporary hack-around is this:

```
def as_dict(vector):
    """Convert an RPy2 ListVector to a Python dict"""
    result = {}
    for i, name in enumerate(vector.names):
        if isinstance(vector[i], robjects.ListVector):
            result[name] = as_dict(vector[i])
        elif len(vector[i]) == 1:
            result[name] = vector[i][0]
        else:
            result[name] = vector[i]
    return result

as_dict(a)
{'foo': 'barbat', 'fizz': 123.0}

b = robjects.r('list(foo=list(bar=1, bat=c("one","two")), fizz=c(123,345))')
as_dict(b)
{'fizz': <FloatVector - Python:0x108f7e950 / R:0x7febcba86b90>
 [123.000000, 345.000000],
 'foo': {'bar': 1.0, 'bat': <StrVector - Python:0x108f7edd0 / R:0x7febcba86ea0>
  [str, str]}}
```

So, the question is... Is there a better way or something built into RPy2 that I should be using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think to get a r vector into a `dictionary` does not have to be so involving, how about this:

```
In [290]:

dict(zip(a.names, list(a)))
Out[290]:
{'fizz': <FloatVector - Python:0x08AD50A8 / R:0x10A67DE8>
[123.000000],
 'foo': <StrVector - Python:0x08AD5030 / R:0x10B72458>
['barbat']}
In [291]:

dict(zip(a.names, map(list,list(a))))
Out[291]:
{'fizz': [123.0], 'foo': ['barbat']}
```

And of course, if you don't mind using `pandas`, it is even easier. The result will have `numpy.array` instead of `list`, but that will be OK in most cases:

```
In [294]:

import pandas.rpy.common as com
com.convert_robj(a)
Out[294]:
{'fizz': [123.0], 'foo': array(['barbat'], dtype=object)}
```

Comment: Nice! The dict(zip(... approach doesn't handle the nested list (my second example above), but it's much more concise for the simple case. I like it.

Comment: Is it safe to do this with at `DataFrame` as well?

Answer (score 18):

## Simple R list to Python dictionary:

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> a = robjects.r('list(foo="barbat", fizz=123)')
>>> d = { key : a.rx2(key)[0] for key in a.names }
>>> d
{'foo': 'barbat', 'fizz': 123.0}
```

## Arbitrary R object to Python object using R RJSONIO JSON serialization/deserialization

On R server:   install.packages("RJSONIO", dependencies = TRUE)

```
>>> ro.r("library(RJSONIO)")
<StrVector - Python:0x300b8c0 / R:0x3fbccb0>
[str, str, str, ..., str, str, str]
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> rjson = robjects.r(' toJSON( list(foo="barbat", fizz=123, lst=list(33,"bb")) )  ')
>>> pyobj = json.loads( rjson[0] )
>>> pyobj
{u'lst': [33, u'bb'], u'foo': u'barbat', u'fizz': 123}
>>> pyobj['lst']
[33, u'bb']
>>> pyobj['lst'][0]
33
>>> pyobj['lst'][1]
u'bb'
>>> rjson = robjects.r(' toJSON( list(foo="barbat", fizz=123, lst=list( key1=33,key2="bb")) )  ')
>>> pyobj = json.loads( rjson[0] )
>>> pyobj
{u'lst': {u'key2': u'bb', u'key1': 33}, u'foo': u'barbat', u'fizz': 123}
```

Comment: Clever use of JSON as an intermediate.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with a deeply nested structure of different rpy2 vector types. I couldn't find a direct answer anywhere on stackoverflow, so here's my solution.
Using CT Zhu's answer, I came up with the following code to convert the complete structure to python types recursively.

```python
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np

from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame, FloatVector, IntVector, StrVector, ListVector, Matrix


def recurse_r_tree(data):
    """
    step through an R object recursively and convert the types to python types as appropriate. 
    Leaves will be converted to e.g. numpy arrays or lists as appropriate and the whole tree to a dictionary.
    """
    r_dict_types = [DataFrame, ListVector]
    r_array_types = [FloatVector, IntVector, Matrix]
    r_list_types = [StrVector]
    if type(data) in r_dict_types:
        return OrderedDict(zip(data.names, [recurse_r_tree(elt) for elt in data]))
    elif type(data) in r_list_types:
        return [recurse_r_tree(elt) for elt in data]
    elif type(data) in r_array_types:
        return np.array(data)
    else:
        if hasattr(data, "rclass"):  # An unsupported r class
            raise KeyError('Could not proceed, type {} is not defined'
                           'to add support for this type, just add it to the imports '
                           'and to the appropriate type list above'.format(type(data)))
        else:
            return data  # We reached the end of recursion
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Please let us know, how we can have an R matrix in conversion too?

Comment: @moha I amended to code above to include the R Matrix. Please give me feedback. I also changed the error message to help add support for more R types.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do the following:

**In**

```
dict(a.items())
```

**Out**

```
{'foo': R object with classes: ('character',) mapped to:
 ['barbat'], 'fizz': R object with classes: ('numeric',) mapped to:
 [123.000000]}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is my function for the conversion from an rpy2 ListVector to a python dict, capable of handling nested lists:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

def r_list_to_py_dict(r_list):
    converted = {}
    for name in r_list.names:
        val = r_list.rx(name)[0]
        if isinstance(val, ro.vectors.DataFrame):
            converted[name] = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(val)
        elif isinstance(val, ro.vectors.ListVector):
            converted[name] = r_list_to_py_dict(val)
        elif isinstance(val, ro.vectors.FloatVector) or isinstance(val, ro.vectors.StrVector):
            if len(val) == 1:
                converted[name] = val[0]
            else:
                converted[name] = list(val)
        else: # single value
            converted[name] = val
    return converted
```

Answer (score 2):

With the new version of pandas, one could also do,

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
a = robjects.r('list(foo="barbat", fizz=123)')

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
print(pandas2ri.ri2py(a.names))
temp = pandas2ri.ri2py(a)
print(temp[0])
print(temp[1])
```

Comment: what do you get back for `> type(temp)` after the above code? I still see temp as a `rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector`

Answer (score 1):

A simple function to convert nested R named lists into a nested Python dictionary :

```
def rext(r):
    """
    Returns a R named list as a Python dictionary
    """
    # In case `r` is not a named list
    try:
        # No more names, just return the value!
        if r.names == NULL:
            # If more than one value, return numpy array (or list)
            if len(list(r)) > 1:
                return np.array(r)
            # Just one value, return the value
            else:
                return list(r)[0]
        # Create dictionary to hold named list as key-value
        dic = {}
        for n in list(r.names):
            dic[n] = rext(r[r.names.index(n)])
        return dic
    # Uh-oh `r` is not a named list, just return `r` as is
    except:
        return r
```