# rpy2: output of json.dumps() is really not proper json object

Tags: python, r, json, rpy2

in my back-end code, I called R function from python with `rpy2`, and I have dictionary output from my R function, and I need to render it as `JSON` at my server endpoint. But output of `json.dumps()` for my dictionary is really not `JSON` object. I figured out because output of R function as `StrVector`, I have to stringify output data in dictionary then use `json.dumps`, but still couldn't get proper formatted JSON.

why `json.dumps` behaved stranged on data in the dictionary? what's the right way to get proper JSON structured data at the endpoint? any thought?

**input data in dictionary**:

here is the data in the dictionary that returned by R function. type of this dictionary is `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>`

```
mydict = {"score":[72.188,62.0955,19.3374],"category":"medium",
"guidance":"text description","readiness":true,
"features_used":{"name":"gcstotal","value":null,
"range_value":[3.6667,5,6.3333,7.6667,9,10.3333,11.6667,13,14.3333],
"range_frequency":[0.0024,0,0.0049,0.0016,0.0073,0.0195,0.0098,0.0138,0.9406],"importance":0}}
```

**update**:

I just did quality check for `mydict`, it is `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>`, so I tried below in my code:

```
json.dumps(str(mydict))
```

then I ended up below output. I called R function from python, and I used `rpy2` to do so, but the output of `json.dumps()` for StrVector is not really json. why? any idea?

when I feed this dictionary to `json.dumps(mydict )`, I have this output:

```
"{\"score\":[72.188,62.0955,19.3374],\"category\":\"medium\",
\"guidance\":\"text description\",\"readiness_flag\":true,
\"features_used\":{\"name\":\"gcstotal\",\"value\":null,
\"range_value\":[3.6667,5,6.3333,7.6667,9,10.3333,11.6667,13,14.3333],
\"range_frequency\":[0.0024,0,0.0049,0.0016,0.0073,0.0195,0.0098,0.0138,0.9406],\"importance\":0}} \n"
```

I just don't understand why end up with non-JSON object from `json.dumps`. is it a problem from `json.dumps` or I used wrong way for jsonify dictionary at server endpoint? why I have above output? any idea? thanks

**update 2:**:

after I tried @Victor S solution, it worked for pasted dictionary, but I am not sure I can decorate mydict object as follow as follow:

```
def post(self):
        if not request.get_json():
            return bad_request('No input data provided')
        raw_dict = request.json
        input_json = json.dumps(raw_dict)
        mydict = my_R_func(input_json)
        mydict = """mydict"""  ## inspired from @Victor S
        res = json.loads(str(mydict))
        res = json.dumps(res)
        return jsonify(res)
```

can I decorate mydict = my_R_func(input_json); mydict = """ mydict """ ? is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your process is not quite clear. Please provide a full code block with all `import` lines (not line snippets) of your Python script and JSON data. Code + data = [mcve]. Need to know the context more. Not quite clear why R is used at all.

Comment: @Parfait what I did is call R function from python with `rpy2`, and I got dictionary like object but it is in `StrVector()` type. seems `pandas.rpy.common` might help, I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.rpy'` . any idea? I am just curious how below answer was generated. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call **json.dumps()** you need to pass it a valid Python dict. For example your **"readiness":true** true here would throw a error as it's not a valid Python Boolean variable, but rather this is JSON syntax.

Try the following to get around this issue.

```
import json

mydict = """{"score":[72.188,62.0955,19.3374],"category":"medium",
"guidance":"text description","readiness":true,
"features_used":{"name":"gcstotal","value":null,
"range_value":[3.6667,5,6.3333,7.6667,9,10.3333,11.6667,13,14.3333],
"range_frequency":[0.0024,0,0.0049,0.0016,0.0073,0.0195,0.0098,0.0138,0.9406],"importance":0}}"""

# convert to string
mydict_str = json.loads(mydict)

# to json obj.
tojson = json.dumps(mydict_str , indent=4)
print(tojson)
```

Comment: do you think is there any way we can convert `StrVector` to normal dictionary? why we envelope `mydict inside """"""`?

Comment: can I do res = """mydict"""? because in mydict was output from my function, seems I have to decorate whatever I got from my function inside """ """. how can I decorate output object inside """ """?

Comment: I got above `mydict` after I printed out how `mydict` looks like, how am I gonna decorate output object, like `mydict`? your solution worked but I have to wrap up non-printed `mydict` inside """ """. any idea?

Comment: please take a look my `update 2` on my post. Is that doable? thanks

Comment: @jyson what does "raw_dict" print out?

Comment: If your "raw_dict" or "input_json" appears as in your first example "input data in dictionary:", you should be able to call json.load(raw_dict) followed by json.dumps(mydict ) to serialize to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dict(zip(mydict.names, map(list, list(mydict))))
```

Credit to @CT Zhu for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152160/converting-an-rpy2-listvector-to-a-python-dictionary)

apparently this won't handle nested lists, so alternatively you can use rpy2 (pip install rpy2):

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

pandas2ri.ri2py(mydict)
Out[294]:
{"score":[72.188,62.0955,19.3374],"category":"medium",
"guidance":"text description","readiness":true,
"features_used":{"name":"gcstotal","value":null,
"range_value":[3.6667,5,6.3333,7.6667,9,10.3333,11.6667,13,14.3333],
"range_frequency":[0.0024,0,0.0049,0.0016,0.0073,0.0195,0.0098,0.0138,0.9406],"importance":0}}
```

[rpy2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/r_interface.html)

Comment: how did you install pandas.rpy? I have this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.rpy'`.I tried `dict(zip(mydict.names, map(list, list(mydict))))`, but it is not working. can you point me out how you make `pandas.rpy` worked?

Comment: I checked, and `pandas.rpy2` was deprecated. how did you get above your output? I am just surprised by how `pandas.rpy` worked for you.

Comment: I installed `pip install pandas==0.25.3`, still same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.rpy'`. any idea how do you get above output?
`

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Please see here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/r_interface.html

Comment: please stay hold, let me try it before confirming your output is right. thanks

Comment: you have to `pip install rpy2` it is a different package.  I was initially assuming the linked answer was still a valid solution.

Comment: yep, I installed `rpy2` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas). your solution works partially, why there is error: `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`. seems logical value is not addressed. any possible update?

Comment: hmm... in Python, true is represented as True, and false is represented as False.  It seems that because they are lowercase, and not quoted strings it is resulting in a NameError.  Are you able to modify the R object before conversion?  Alternatively you could define the variable `true = True` prior to conversion, but this would not be ideal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213435/discussion-between-jyson-and-rexovas).